# In App Purchase Request Fail

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Why can't I access the "request didReceiveResponse:" function, in spite of creating a valid product ID in iTunes Connect. Every time the request fails. What may be the error?

Comment: Are you running on the simulator or a real device?

Comment: In app purchase are not available in the simulator. You need to test in a real device